# Datagridview checkbox column has a dead area

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` (winforms) with a `checkbox` column as well as other text-based columns.  I've successfully worked through most of the common issues around `checkbox` columns which are very well documented on this site.

However, I have 1 remaining problem.  I am able to click "directly" on a `checkbox` and it does respond the way I want.  However, if I carefully move the mouse pointer between the cell boundary and the `checkbox` control, and mouse click, I am able to select the cell but the state of the `checkbox` does not toggle.  This problem is much more evident when the row height is bigger for a given row.

Thanks for any help

NOTE: this is not, I repeat **NOT**, the issue that occurs when focus moves off a given checkbox cell after it is checked.  I have that one solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue.  This is simply how it is supposed to work.  For a grid column you can have cellclick events and cellcontentclick events.  Since I want the checkbox to check when I click anywhere inside the cell, I should use cellclick.  Among other events you will need to listen for, I added the following to my code:

```
    private void Grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex == 1) && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            this.MyGrid[1, e.RowIndex].Value = !(bool)this.MyGrid[1, e.RowIndex].Value;
            this.MyGrid.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```